Error CS1003 Syntax Error ',' expected (Unity C#) 2D RPG Game
I'm trying to get knockback to work in my game, but I'm getting error CS1003. The error says "Assets\Scripts\Enemy.cs(17,31): error CS1003: Syntax error, ',' expected". Here's my code:
`using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using UnityEngine;

 public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour
 {
     Animator animator;
     Rigidbody2D rb;

     // Start is called before the first frame update
     public float Health
     {
        set
        {
             if(value < health)
             {
                 OnHit(Vector2 knockback);
             }
             health = value;
             print(value);

             if(health <= 0)
             {
                 Defeated();
             }
        }
        get
        {
             return health;
        }
     }
     public float health = 20;

     private void Start()
     {
         animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
    
         rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
     }
     public void Defeated()
     {
         animator.SetTrigger("Defeated");
     }
     public void OnHit()
     {

         //Apply force to enemy
         rb.AddForce(knockback);

         //animator.SetTrigger("IsHit");
     }

     public void RemoveEnemy()
     {
         Destroy(gameObject);
     }
 }`

Most of the things I tried just created more errors. I feel like I missing something simple.

if (value < health)
{
Vector2 knockback = new Vector2(-5f, 2f); // Define your knockback vector here
OnHit(knockback); // Pass the knockback vector
}

@ømi OnHit doesn't even take any parameters to begin with ;) The next error will be that within OnHit the knockback isn't recognized .. it doesn't exist

OnHit(Vector2 knockback); is not correct. It doesn't make sense. (17,31) in the error message tells you the line and space where the error is located.

In C#, when you define new method, you need to provide parameter type:
public void MyMethod(int myParameter)
{
   //code here
}

And when you call that method you need to provide parameter with that type (but not define type):
public void Main()
{
   int customNumber = 5;
   MyMethod(customNumber);
}    

So that error telling you that compiler(or ide or whatever) waiting for comma between "Vector2" and "knockback". It thinking it is two parameters for that method. So you need to define knockback vector parameter and pass it into method.
Vector2 knockback = new Vector2(); //I don't remember what parameters it want, so check Unity documentation
OnHit(knockback);


Thank you this does clear up the error I was having, but it seems the main problem I having is sharing the value of Vector2 knockback from one script to another. Do you having any advice on how to send the value of a vector from one script to another?

Sure (but I havn't used Unity for years so may be there some build-in functionality that handle that but...) you need to have reference of that class inside another class so when you update something in Class1 you can call Class2.UpdateMyValues(newValue). Also you can have some generic MainController class where you add all you references, so you can control them from there. It would be something like Observer pattern. About different patterns you can read here https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/csharp
